# Javascript array.prototype.map when/why use third argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I recently noticed that when using `array.prototype.map()`, my callback function may accept a third argument which is the array I'm mapping. I wonder if there are any use cases for this argument because inside the callback function, the array can be accessed anyways.

**If I access the array I'm mapping inside the callback function, why/when should I rather use the third argument instead of just accessing the array?**

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/0qz362u4/)

Even though both methods should work fine in every use case I can imagine, I'd like to know which is the recommended way to do it and why.

Comment: In short, you may not have access to the array or you may not want to refer to it. Case 1 `myArr.filter(x => x % 2 == 1).map((x, i, arr) => x+arr.length)` - it's a chained operation, so after the first chain, you can't refer to `myArr` as your working data. You can stop the chain, assign to a variable and use that but it's a bit wasteful. Case 2: your callback is in another scope to the array you have `callback = (x, i, arr) => x+arr.length` in one place and you do `myArr.map(callback)` in another, so you cannot refer to the original array in the callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer was already (coincidentally) given in the flagged dupe. Check it out [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500430/1813169).

---

You may wish to reference the original array in a generic fashion. For instance, the callback may be a separate function, not just an anonymous one as is usually seen:

```js
function arrayMapper(val, idx, arr) {
  // Some operations which use arr
}

myArray.map(arrayMapper);
myOtherArray.map(arrayMapper);
```

Note how each in execution of `arrayMapper`, the `arr` parameter refers to a different array in the outer scope.

Comment: here still same result as example was on global context. Here still i can access original myArray without needing 3rd argument.  See my answer which depicts its more likely use with object oriented programming using functions:

Comment: @vipulpatel Does the update make my intention clearer?

Comment: yes here i could see if were- use separate function for two different array. Could see my example as well with Object Oriented programming as now a days no one write code in global scope with ES6 or Typescript and many other provides **class** style programming

Answer (score 8):

The third argument can be useful when you are chaining several array methods and need to access the intermediate state of the array (result of the previous operation):

```
const source = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5];
source
  .filter(n => n >= 0)
  .map((n, index, arr) => {
     // arr contains only non-negative numbers
     // here you may have some logic that rely on it
     return n;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using normal global context where this need does not arise.See below example where you are **not** using **arrow** function (which preserve the current context) with Object oriented function programming. At that time it helps as third property. In first example, i cant access **this.numbers** in anonymous function as anonymous fun has its own context. Here it useful when you want to access original array for operarions

**working** example :

```js
function Demo (numbers){
   this.numbers = numbers;
}

Demo.prototype.doMap = function () {
 return this.numbers.map(function(num, index, array) {
     return array[num]
  });
}

var obj  = new Demo([1, 2, 4, 2, 3]);

console.log(obj.doMap()); // will work
```

**non working example**  if i don't pass array, it will throw error.

```js
function Demo (numbers){
   this.numbers = numbers;
}

Demo.prototype.doMap = function () {
 return this.numbers.map(function(num, index, array) {
     return this.numbers[num] // cant access original number array using this (this refers to context of anonymous function)
  });
}

var obj  = new Demo([1, 2, 4, 2, 3]);

console.log(obj.doMap()); // throw error
```

Comment: This is the *second* argument to `map`. OP is talking about the third argument given to the callback - the array itself `arr.map(function (item, index, array) {}, thisArg)`

Comment: Sorry !! I just got the question and i updated the answer :)

Comment: @VLAZ Hi, Now it makes sense ?